# How do I format a textbox in Excel using the response from a user form?

Tags: forms, excel, vba, textbox, format

I am new to Excel and trying to create a user form where the user will input answers to a few simple questions. Depending on the answers given, I want to format the color of regular text-boxes in the spreadsheet. Is there a certain type of function that I need to use? Can anyone provide sample code lines to try using?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to SO Nasra :) `an anyone provide sample code lines to try using? ` Well SO doesn't function this way. You will have to provide the code that you tried and show us which part are you stuck with. I see that you are new to Excel and if you are wondering what Form / ActiveX controls are then have a look at this link. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/overview-of-forms-form-controls-and-activex-controls-on-a-worksheet-HA010237663.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **Record Macro**.

[image]

It will create a new module and you can copy / paste from there.